# Eclipse can be used to write assembly code and run it?

Tags: eclipse, assembly

Who know the answer ? Please tell me, thanks!

Comment: Eclipse CDT has some support for assembly language.

Answer (score 2):

Yes and No. 
You need an Eclipse-Plugin to code an Assembler-Program and at least an assembler-compiler.

Depend of your needs, the AVR-Eclipse-Plugin may be a good choice.

Run and Assembly? Yes.

Comment: i dont think that all compilerdepend metainfos will be ported, so: in compliance with the requirements, yes.

Please understand AVR as an editor, not an compiler.